# Having a sample document that matches this regular expression query

Tags: mongodb

So I was reading Kyle's book and came across this example he has used for using regular expressions to match some text:

```
db.reviews.find({
    user_id: ObjectId("4c4b1476238d3b4dd5000001"),
    text: /best|worst/i
})
```

But it doesn't have a sample document so I can't imagine how a document is structured that he is using for this example. So can you please draw a quick document that the regular expression above works on it?
As far as I can tell it has a _id key of course and a text key, but what the values of that text key look like?

Thanks.

Comment: The `text` is probably the review (as in *restaurant review*) itself, the `user_id` is probably the reviewer.

Comment: Yes but I wanna know how the values of text key look like? Is it like a full sentence that reviewer has written like "this is the worst food ever" and this regex is finding the word "worst" in the whole sentence or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine something like this, there is a user collection elsewhere, and this is a collection of all reviews every user ever wrote.   When you want to get all reviews by a particular user, you query for all reviews which match that user's id - that's the user_id part.   Now you decide you only want the reviews that have the word best or the word worst in it (regardless of capitalization).  That's the second part of the query.

Assuming the three documents below all had matching user_id then first and third would match the text query but the middle one would not.

```
{
   user_id: ObjectId(),
   text : "This was the worst one of my life!"
}

{

   user_id: ObjectId(),
   text : "Totally awesome, couldn't be better!"
}

{
   user_id: ObjectId(),
   text : "BEST EVAH!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asya, that's powerful. Now the question is how well such a text search will perform if the text blob is like 45 Mega Bytes of text? Not recommended for such a thing? What would you recommend in that case?

Comment: MongoDB document size limit is 16MB, but that's besides the point - the issue is that this is a slow query even on short text field if you have a lot of documents.  You can use an index for this type of text search.  There are probably better (more specialized solutions for this type of problem.